# How does the Mockito-Kotlin mock function work without a class parameter?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, mockito-kotlin

Mockito is a mocking framework ( that tastes really good  )

mockito-kotlin is a small library that provides helper functions to work with Mockito in Kotlin.

Normally from Kotlin to mock an interface with mockito I would write something like

```
val mockBookService = Mockito.mock(BookService::class.java)
```

But when using mockito-kotlin I can change this to

```
val mockBookService : BookService = mock()
```

so my question is how does the mock function know which interface to mock without the supplied class parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There is one most general type that could be used in `mock()` to make that declaration pass a type-check: `val mockBookService: BookService = mock<BookService>()`.

So the type system figures that out, and uses it.

Comment: is this similar to how ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>() works in Java, deducing the right hand side from the declared type? 
Is it necessary for the mock function to be inline and reified to use the 'figured-out' type?